# How to get data separately on one or more conditions in CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table something like this with lots of IDs..

[image]

In the table I have Id. Each Id has some value and the value's corresponding date. I need to get the Ids separately for which

1. If value is not null then it's corresponding date should also be not null
2. If value is null then no need to check it's corresponding date

So in the query if I pass 1 as a parameter, result table Id (101, & 104) will be shown and if I pass 2 as parameter, Id (102 & 103) will be shown together

Comment: Yuck!!! This violates 1NF with an anti-pattern known as repeating groups. Those date/value sets should each be a row. Consider how painful this would be if you need to add a 5th set....or 30!!! Fix the data structure and you can use constraints to enforce data integrity.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by shown together? Two queries? Sorted together?

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for pointing out. But the table is given in this format only. If you can help i will be thankful. no need to say Yuck.... thank you.

Comment: So you are saying you can't fix the design? That is the cause of your pain here. You are stuck making queries to simulate normalized data like the fine example that Salaman A posted.

Comment: @Nidhi I have revised the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition:

> 1. If value is not null then it's corresponding date should also be not null
> 2. If value is null then no need to check it's corresponding date

Could be written as:

```
(value1 IS NULL OR date1 IS NOT NULL)
```

Create the condition for each pair and combine using `AND`:

```
SELECT *
FROM table_with_lots_of_ids
WHERE
(value1 IS NULL OR date1 IS NOT NULL) AND
(value2 IS NULL OR date2 IS NOT NULL) AND
(value3 IS NULL OR date3 IS NOT NULL) AND
(value4 IS NULL OR date4 IS NOT NULL)
```

The above will select row number 101 and 104. Wrap the where clause inside `NOT (...)` to get row number 102 and 103.